# Selenium can not take data

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When I try to get information it returns empty list. If I write different class such as 'tr-indent2' or something it returns value in a bad format which means it can take data but not for every class.

```
liste=[]

linkss=['https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT05768724','https://ClinicalTrials.gov/show/NCT05768607']
for data in linkss:
    path=r"C:\Users\kaant\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
    service=Service(executable_path=path)
    options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
    options.headless = True 
    driver = uc.Chrome() 
    driver.get(data)  
    time.sleep(5) 
    infos=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, value="ct-layout_table tr-tableStyle tr-moreInfo")
    c=[]
    
   
    for info in infos:
        c.append(info.text)
        
        
    liste.append(c)
        
        
    driver.quit()
```

How can I get this class? Thanks

Comment: if it returnes an empty list its because it cant find any elements with that class combination

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is nested in several other `div's`, so you need to use `By.XPATH`:

```
infos=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="tr-indent1"]//div[@class="tr-indent2"]//table[@class="ct-layout_table tr-tableStyle tr-moreInfo"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the required information you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05768724")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.ct-layout_table.tr-tableStyle.tr-moreInfo")])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT05768724")
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='ct-layout_table tr-tableStyle tr-moreInfo']")])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  ```